# find value and call another value - php arrays

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I have the below array coming though, ideally I am looking for a way of matching one value and printing out another value.

e.g.

```
if($randomvalue  == $cards[Card][unit_id]) { echo $cards[SaleDetail][date_pid_signed]; }
```

I'm not sure exactly how to go about getting the above to work with the current array structure as below.

Any ideas how I can get around this?

Thanks

```
$cards = Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Card] => Array
            (
                [id] => 210
                [property_id] => 4
                [unit_id] => 90
            )

        [SaleDetail] => Array
            (
                [property_agent] => 
                [date_pid_signed] => 2012-06-15
                [property_date_listed] => 
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Card] => Array
            (
                [id] => 209
                [property_id] => 4
                [unit_id] => 103
            )

        [SaleDetail] => Array
            (
                [property_agent] => 
                [date_pid_signed] => 2011-10-21
                [property_date_listed] => 
            )

    )
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($cards as $card){
    if($randomvalue  == $card[Card][unit_id]) { 
       echo $card[SaleDetail][date_pid_signed]; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$cards[0]['Card']['unit_id']` and `$cards[0]['SaleDetail']['date_pid_signed']`. Notice the indexes `[0]`. You can then use `[1]`.

You might also want to check `foreach` or `for` loops!

Comment: Thanks however how do I do it for any of the arrays. i.e. the [0] goes up to 100 + (or more), above was just an example snippit. Ideally I need it to be something like $cards[$X]['Card']['unit_id']

Comment: i mentioned about foreach or for loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($randomvalue  == $cards[0][Card][unit_id]) { echo $cards[0][SaleDetail][date_pid_signed]; }
```

also you can do

```
foreach($cards as $card)
{
    if($randomvalue  == $card[Card][unit_id]) 
    { 
       echo $card[SaleDetail][date_pid_signed]; 
     }
}
```